# Bash join over multiple fields

Tags: linux, bash, unix, join

I have two files that look like this :

file1

```
a b 1 1
b d 2 3
```

file2

```
a 10 11
b 20 21
d 30 31
```

And I would like to join them in order to have the following output, which is the first file with what's written in file2 for first two fields:

```
a b 1 1 10 11 20 21
b d 2 3 20 21 30 31
```

I tried to use join, but I can't manage to join files according to the first two fields of file1.

Comment: Answered hundreds of times, use awk.

Comment: No way of doing it with join only?

Comment: Not that i am aware of no.

Comment: Post the attempt you tried with `join`

Comment: Couldn't do better than `join -j 1 file1 file2`, I thought there would be a way to join multiple fields like `join -11 -21 -12 -21 file1 file2` or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you want to join on two lines, you'll need to join twice, piping the stdout of the first to the stdin of the second:

```
join -11 -21 file1 file2 | join -12 -21 - file2
```

Edit: Ah shoot, that reverses the order of the first two fields, is that ok?

```
b a 1 1 10 11 20 21
d b 2 3 20 21 30 31
```

Edit 2: This might be better -- if you reverse the order of the joins, you'll get the 1st two columns in the right order but the joined columns will be swapped:

```
join -12 -21 file1 file2 | join -12 -21 - file2
```

Yields:

```
a b 1 1 20 21 10 11
b d 2 3 30 31 20 21
```

Heh ok I think we got it -- edit 3 with suggestion from Michael Vehrs:

```
join -11 -21 file1 file2 | join -o "1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 1.6 2.2 2.3" -12 -21 - file2
```

Yields:

```
a b 1 1 10 11 20 21
b d 2 3 20 21 30 31
```

Comment: I'd really like to keep the order.
I have this `join -11 -21 t1 t2 | join -12 -21 - t2 | awk '{print $2 " " $1 " " $3 " " $4 " " $5 " " $6 " " $7 " " $8}'` but I feel like there is a better option.

Comment: Your second edit inverts values from a and b instead of a and b.

Comment: It's clumsy, but you can fix the order of fields with the `-o` option, at least with GNU `join`.

Comment: Ah nice, I saw the `-o FORMAT` option in the man page but it's pretty sparsely documented there.